# How to use different c# primitive data types in EF Core Find method

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am buidling an EF Core application. In my `dbContext` there are different models where primary key can be either `int` or `long` data type. I am using Generic repository pattern in my application.

```
public TEntityDto GetById(long id)
{
    var entity = _context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
    return Mapper.Map<TEntityDto>(entity);
}
```

I need to pass both `int` or `long` data type value. But if I passed a `int` data type value I am getting following error.

> The key value at position 0 of the call to 'DbSet<>.Find' was of type
> 'long', which does not match the property type of 'int'.

How can I use both `long` and `int` data type in Generic repository class ?

Comment: use `dynamic` which resolves the type at runtime. i.e. `GetById(dynamic id)`

Comment: I would avoid `dynamic` for that purpose. That is generally bad advice. The infrastructure required to use dynamic is not unsubstantial and is quite overkill for this case. That said, please keep in mind that Entity framework **is already** an implementation of both the generic repository and the Unit of work  patterns. You are  abstracting away something that has already been abstracted away.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 but there are some advantages of using repository pattern with entity framework, rather than implementing its out of the box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'object' instead of 'long' for the parameter type. With your code the parameter is always converted to 'long', hence the exception.

```
public TEntityDto GetById(object id)
{
   var entity = _context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
   return Mapper.Map<TEntityDto>(entity);
}
```